# Select all items that have matching tags

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, sql-order-by

Suppose I have the following Django models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blog = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class ArticleTag(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Add some data:

```
            ArticleID       Rating          Blog
         -----------------------------------------
article1 ->     1             3             CNN
article2 ->     2             2             BBC
article3 ->     3             5             BBC
article4 ->     4             9             NTV


ArticleID      tag
-------------------
    1         tag1
    1         tag2
    1         tag3
    2         tag1
    2         tag4
    3         tag5
    4         tag6
    4         tag7
```

Suppose we have a user that likes `tag1`, `tag2`, `tag6` and `BBC`. All the articles match the requirements, because article1 has `tag1` and `tag2`, article4 has `tag1`, article2 and article3 are from `BBC`.

If we order them by rating: `article4`, `article3`, `article1`, `article2`.

However, I need to order items by the number of matching tags they have + blog first, and then by rating as the second ordering parameter. So I expect the results in the following order:

1. article1 - `tag1` and `tag2`, rating=3
2. article2 - `tag1` and `BBC`, rating=2
3. article4 - `tag6`, rating=9
4. article3 - `BBC`, rating=5

Is it possible to do this in Django? If not, what about PostgreSQL?

Comment: whats the type of your data ? (item1 and rating and tag) ?

Comment: Please add the Django model definitions :)

Comment: The problem is explained very clearly, which makes the question stand out in a positive way. Wouldn't be a bad idea to add your version of Postgres (and Django), too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL query could look like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Article a
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT ArticleID, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   ArticleTag
   WHERE  tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag6')   -- your tags here
   GROUP  BY ArticleID
   ) t ON t.ArticleID = a.ID
ORDER BY t.ct DESC NULLS LAST
       , (a.blog = 'BBC') DESC NULLS LAST   -- your blog here
       , rating DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Basically:

1. Count the matching tags per `ArticleID` in subquery `t`.
2. `LEFT JOIN` the main table to it with data for secondary (`blog`) and tertiary (`rating`) sort criteria.
3. `ORDER BY` the three criteria, `ct` first, `blog` next, `rating` last. All of them descending (highest value first). That works for the boolean expression `(a.blog = 'BBC')` as well, because `TRUE` (1) sorts before `FALSE` (0) in descending order.

**Important:** In descending order NULL values would sort first, so `NULLS LAST` is needed if there *can* be NULL values (and does not hurt if there cannot).

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Even if all your columns are defined `NOT NULL`, `ct` can still be NULL due to the `LEFT JOIN`.

If Django preserves mixed case names with double-quotes, you have to do that in SQL, too. Otherwise all identifiers are cast to lower case.

Answer (score 1):

The query could be simpler I believe :)
There is no real need for a join here. Here's the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e565/10

```
SELECT
  article.ArticleID,
  COUNT(DISTINCT tag.tag),
  COUNT(DISTINCT article.Blog LIKE 'BBC'),
  COUNT(DISTINCT tag.tag) + COUNT(DISTINCT article.Blog LIKE 'BBC'),
  article.rating
FROM article
LEFT JOIN tag
  ON tag.ArticleID = article.ArticleID
WHERE tag.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag6') OR article.Blog LIKE 'BBC'
GROUP BY
  article.ArticleID,
  article.rating
ORDER BY
  COUNT(DISTINCT tag.tag) + COUNT(DISTINCT article.Blog LIKE 'BBC') DESC,
  rating DESC
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you explain why this is better, because you also have a join? Also there is some problem with COUNT(), it displays same values for tags and blogs.

Comment: @nickbusted: joins are generally easier to optimize for a database so I generally prefer to avoid subqueries. As for the count problem... I forgot to add a `DISTINCT` to those. Fixing it now :)