# PostgreSQL - string_agg with limited number of elements

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to limit the number of elements in the following `string_agg` function?

```
 string_agg(distinct(tag),', ')
```

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the query? You can achieve your results with a subquery and `row_number`, but you might be able to get it work with `limit` by itself.

Comment: You cannot limit function itself, but, expanding the problem, why do you need this? Maybe we ca find another way.

Comment: Can you clarify this question: Do you mean to limit the *size* or the *number of elements*?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Number of elements. The reason why I do not want to write any subqueries is because I already have them in the query. Actually you helped me with the query, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26831313/1477118) question. Thank you again!

Comment: @nickbusted: Even if you already have subqueries, integrate `LIMIT` into an existing one, or add another subquery with `LIMIT` to limit the number of elements. That's the most effective answer for what you are asking. A window function is typically more expensive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not aware that you can limit it in the `string_agg()` function.  You can limit it in other ways:

```
select postid, string_agg(distinct(tag), ', ')
from table t
group by postid
```

Then you can do:

```
select postid, string_agg(distinct (case when seqnum <= 10 then tag end), ', ')
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (partition by postid order by tag) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by postid
```

Comment: Thanks. I prefer to avoid any more subqueries. I will probably avoid using string_agg.

Answer (score 26):

There are two more ways.

1. make an array from rows, limit it, and then concatenate into string:

   ```
   SELECT array_to_string((array_agg(DISTINCT tag))[1:3], ', ') FROM tbl
   ```

("array[1:3]" means: take items from 1 to 3 from array)

2. concatenate rows into string without limit, then use "substring" to trim it:

   ```
   string_agg(distinct(tag),',')
   ```

If you know that your "tag" field cannot contain `,` character then you can select all text before nth occurence of your `,`

```
SELECT substring(
string_agg(DISTINCT tag, ',') || ','
from '(?:[^,]+,){1,3}')
FROM tbl
```

This substring will select 3 or less strings divided by `,`. To exclude trailing `,` just add `rtrim`:

```
SELECT rtrim(substring(
string_agg(DISTINCT tag, ',') || ','
from '(?:[^,]+,){1,3}'), ',')
FROM test
```

Comment: love the array method!

Comment: Nice one, but the last query returns a NULL when you have exactly one element in the tbl. I haven't found an elegant way to deal with this due to the 'substring(.. from ..)' specifics. The first approach is probably slower but does the trick.

Comment: Okay. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 16):

To *"limit the number of elements in the following `string_agg()`"*, use [`LIMIT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) in a subquery:

```
SELECT string_agg(tag, ', ') AS tags
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT tag
   FROM   tbl
-- ORDER  BY tag  -- optionally order to get deterministic result
   LIMIT   123    -- add your limit here
   ) sub;
```

The subquery is no problem for performance at all. **On the contrary**, this is typically **faster**, even if you don't impose a maximum number with `LIMIT`, because the group-wise `DISTINCT` in the aggregate function is more expensive than doing it in a subquery for all rows at once.

Or, to get the *"100 most common tags"*:

```sql
SELECT string_agg(tag, ', ') AS tags
FROM  (
   SELECT tag
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY tag
   ORDER  BY count(*) DESC
   LIMIT  100
   ) sub;
```

Answer (score 3):

Nest your `string_agg` clause in a `split_part`, including the delimiter as the second argument, and the number of elements you need as the final argument. Like so:

```
split_part(string_agg(distinct(tag),', '), ', ', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IN to filter

Like This:

```
Select
  primaryID,
  String_Agg(email, '|') As Email
From
  contacts
Where
  contactID In (Select filter.contactID
  From contacts filter
  Where filter.primaryID = contacts.primaryID
  Order By filter.contactID)
Group By
  primaryID;
```