How to aggregate only parts of members of each group in one query statement in PG?
I have a table people(gid int, name varchar) with data:
gid    name                 
1      Bill
2      Will
2      Musk
2      Jack
1      Martin
1      Jorge

now I want to get a result set like below:
  gid   representative(varchar)
   1     Bill, Martin
   2     Will, Musk

I mean to list out each group with two of people's names of that group as representative. Here the order doesn't matter, the count matters. How to do it in one query statement, i.e. in PG?
After multiple trying for a long while, I can achieve the goal by this statement:
with indexed as(
    select gid,name,row_number() over (partition by gid) as index
    from people
),filtered as(
    select gid, name 
    from indexed where index<3
)
select gid,string_agg(name,',')
from filtered
group by gid;

However, the actual table has huge number rows and more complicated schema. It consumes long time to just create the first CTE table "indexed" because of traversing the whole table.
Is there better resolution to direct database engine to select out just parts of rows for each group at first, without full traversing?

You are determining the row_number for all records, and then discarding all of them, except for the first 2....  Maybe this solution works better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36498909/724039    In case it does not work better, please [edit] the question and add EXPLAIN PLAN for your query

In you table you are talking about a column gid, in your query you have id. Please explain the differences....

It would also help to know which indexes exist on your table people.

@Luuk, you have sharp eyes, I have made typo(acutally paste-error), I corrected it. thanks.

A colleague remainds me of array_sample, and by lucky coincidence, I don't care  which rows would win out( here which two names should be selected out). So the solution in my case is:
select gid,array_sample(array_agg(name),2) from people group by gid

I tested it on my actual "big" table with hundred million rows, It run obviously
much faster than my old CTE solution.

this test (DBFIDDLE), with more records (25000000 on my test)  than fit on DBFIDDLE, shows a less performant answer....   The cte-version needs 6 seconds, this array-sample-version needs 10 seconds.

Do you have a Table with id as primary key?
Then you could give a double subselect a try:
I don't have a clue what the optimizer will make out of it
select id, (select name from (select array_agg(foo.name) name 
    from (select name from people where people.id = a.id LIMIT 2) as  foo) as bar)
from xxx_table a


One option is to use Row_Number() analytic function and STRING_AGG()
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table People As
( Select 1 as gid, 'Bill' as name Union All
  Select 2,        'Will' Union All
  Select 2,        'Musk' Union All
  Select 2,        'Jack' Union All
  Select 1,        'Martin' Union All
  Select 1,        'Jorge' )

--    S Q L : 
SELECT gid, STRING_AGG(name, ', ') as names
FROM   ( Select gid, name, Row_Number() Over(Partition By gid Order By gid) as rn
         From   People )
WHERE  rn <= 2
GROUP BY gid

/*
gid names
--- ---------------
  1 Bill, Martin
  2 Will, Musk      */

See the fiddle here.

I do not think that moving the CTE to a SUBQUERY will have any impact on the speed of the query... (and I tested it too, which proved it.... )

@Luuk Without info about index it's hard to tell, but there are two ctes and here is one subquery partitioning, ordering and grouping by gid. With appropriate index on gid it should be faster. Explain plan could tell...
